# Firebase serve not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools, serve

I've been migrating to Firebase 3.0, and with the new changes, we have to use `firebase serve` on the CLI for local development, and I believe this defaults to port 5000. However, after going through the init process, running `firebase serve` doesn't do anything after "Starting Firebase development server..." even with specifying port 5000. Attempted fixes:

- Tried with other ports, like 5001
- Reinstalled Node (4.x and 6.x)
- Reinstalled NPM
- Removed firebase-cli (since firebase-tools is now being used)
- Reinstalled firebase-tools with npm
- Tweaked `firebase init` endlessly
- Tried on different user accounts on my computer
- Restarted computer
- Checked that port 5000 was free by $`lsof -i tcp:5000`
- Tested address variants like localhost:5000 and like 127.x and 192.x

Here is the debug log:

```
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] Command:      /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase serve -p 5000 --debug
[debug] CLI Version:  3.0.0
[debug] Platform:     darwin
[debug] Node Version: v6.2.0
[debug] Time:         Sun May 22 2016 01:29:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[info] Starting Firebase development server...
[info] 
[info] Project Directory: /Users/user/Documents/localdev/spfwork
```

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854370/firebase-serve-from-vagrant-localhost5000. Essentially, using flags -p 5000 -o <IP> helped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed - `firebase serve` from firebase-tools (npm) was missing a logger for some errors, which I added on a pull request here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/143

My error was that localhost was not starting for some reason, so I changed the command to `firebase serve -p 5000 -o 127.0.0.1`, and specifying the listen port allowed the server to start successfully.

For reference, the error was `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost`

Answer (score 2):

### You could just change your `/etc/hosts` file and use `firebase serve` normally.

To do this:

1. Launch Terminal
2. Type `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and press Return
3. Enter your admin password Paste
4. Paste

```
    ##
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost
```

5. Save the file by pressing Ctrl + O
6. Exit with Ctrl + X

This should fix it.
[See this for more](https://setapp.com/how-to/edit-mac-hosts-file)

Answer (score 0):

If Firebase cannot find the 'Public' folder, this error might show up. In that case, the error can be resolved by putting `index.html` and other static files and app assets of the website within the public folder, and executing `firebase deploy` at the Firebase CLI again.