# Firebase serve from vagrant localhost:5000

Tags: firebase, vagrant

I'm running vagrant/ubuntu 16.04 on mac os high sierra. I have set port forwarding and symlink to awesome.local.com. Basic node.js web app works perfectly and can be viewed on mac chrome browser pointing to awesome.local.com:3000

I want to develop firebase in this environment the same way, and was able to set-up the CLI and logged in fine.

Going through the Firebase Web Codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

When running

```
$ firebase serve
```

Looks like everything is running without error (I did debug):

```
hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
```

When I go to the browser and point to awesome.local.com:5000 I get:

```
This site can’t be reached

awesome.locl.com refused to connect.
Search Google for awesome.local.com:5000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've tried:

- rebuilt dev environment
- reinstalling everything
- other tutorials

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run `firebase serve` against a different host and port, see the help in the CLI:

```
$ firebase serve --help

Usage: serve [options]

start a local server for your static assets


Options:

  -p, --port <port>   the port on which to listen (default: 5000) (default: 5000)
  -o, --host <host>   the host on which to listen (default: localhost) (default: localhost)
  --only <targets>    only serve specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
  --except <targets>  serve all except specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
  -h, --help          output usage information
```

You can change the host and port it listens to with `-p` and `-o`.  The default will only bind to localhost, which will not be accessible to anything other than 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You were correct! It was a setting I had when doing the port forwarding. I had set it for 192.168.68.8. So doing: $ firebase serve -p 5000 -o 192.168.68.8 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @jkpham001 If this answer was helpful to you, please accept it as correct.